# Duplication on a static page displaying two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I'm trying to create a static  page called **Magazine** that displays two different models **Experiences** and **Articles** ordered by date.

However, I'm running into a strange issue where the Experiences model is duplicating on the Magazine page.

Pages Controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  include Pagy::Frontend

  def home
    @experiences = Experience.order('date DESC').limit(1)
    @articles = Article.order('date DESC').limit(1)
  end

  def magazine
    @experiences = Experience.order('date DESC')
    @articles = Article.order('date DESC')
    @feed = (@experiences.to_a + @articles.to_a).sort_by(&:date)
  end
end
```

Static Magazine View Page:

```
<% if @feed.any? %>
  <% @feed.each do |feed| %>
    <% if feed.is_a? Experience %>
      <div id="articles" align="center">
        <% @experiences.each do |experience| %>
          <div class="article-widget">
            <%= link_to experience do %>
              <%= image_tag experience.picture_url, :class=> "img-rounded", width: '80%' if experience.picture.present? %>
            <% end %>
            <div class="article-top-left"><h3><%= experience.category %></h3></div>
            <div class="article-bottom-left"><h4><%= experience.title %><br /> <%= experience.location %></h4></div>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    <% else %>
      <% if feed.is_a? Article %>
        <div id="articles" align="center">
          <% @articles.each do |article| %>
            <div class="article-widget">
              <%= link_to article do %>
                <%= image_tag article.picture, :class=> "img-rounded", width: '80%' if article.picture.present? %>
              <% end %>
              <div class="article-top-left"><h3><%= article.category %></h3></div>
              <div class="article-bottom-left"><h4>Around London with <%= article.title %><br /></h4></div>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I can't spot anything obvious within the controller or view page that would make the Experience model duplicate but I'm really new to coding, so if anyone can help that would be really appreciated! Thanks so much

Comment: Please format your code when making posts to StackOverflow.

Comment: A good way to debug it would be to print out `experience.id` and `article.id` somewhere, so you can make sure it's the same record.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're looping over the combined feed and then the `@experiences` or `@articles` for each feed item.

```
<% if @feed.any? %> # you don't need if since the loop will run 0 times if there are no records 
  <% @feed.each do |feed| %>
    <% if feed.is_a? Experience %>
      <div id="articles" align="center">
        <% @experiences.each do |experience| %> # <-- this is where it goes wrong
```

You can simplefy this code greatly if as there is only one minor difference between the two code branches:

```erb
<% @feed.each do |feed_item| %>
  <div id="articles" align="center">
    <div class="article-widget">
      <%= link_to feed_item do %>
        <%  if feed_item.picture %>
          <!-- You should really consider the accessibility impacts of this. -->
          <!-- see https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/images/functional/ -->
          <%= image_tag feed_item.picture, 
                        class: "img-rounded", 
                        width: "80%",
                        alt: "A text which describes the link"
          %>
        <% else %>
          <!-- You should provide fallback content if there is no image! -->
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
      <div class="article-top-left">
        <h3><%= feed_item.category %></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="article-bottom-left">
        <!-- This could be refactored into a helper method --> 
        <% if feed_item.is_a? Article %>
          <h4>Around London with <%= feed_item.title %></h4>
        <% else %>
          <h4><%= feed_item.title %></h4>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you Max, this has worked perfectly and thank you for the extra tips too. The only thing that doesn't work is my pagination because my code is for one model, rather than the feed. I'll try and work that one out next!

Comment: Dealing with pagination when the source is two different database tables is going to be pretty tricky.